# What do " that" and " at a cost" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

I struggles to understand the  sentence in bold in the following essay because of the usage of **at a cost** and following the word **that**.

> Geothermal energy is natural heat from the interior of the Earth that
>   is converted to heat buildings and generate electricity. The idea of
>   harnessing Earth's internal heat is not new. As early as 1904,
>   geothermal power was used in Italy. Today, Earth's natural internal
>   heat is being used to generate electricity in 21 countries, including
>   Russia, Japan, New Zealand, Iceland, Mexico, Ethiopia, the Philippines
>   and the United States. Total worldwide production is approaching 9000
>   MW. *Some 40 million people today receive their electricity from
>   geothermal energy **at a cost** competitive with **that** of other energy
>   sources*. However, at the global level, geothermal energy supplies less
>   than 0.15% of the total energy supply.

I know what "at a cost" means but  I looked it up  again in the Cambridge Dictionary and I found the following examples which are completely understandable.

> He rescued four people at the cost of his own life.

It means you take a risk, in this case his your life, you are going to lose something but it is not clear how much it will be.

> The cruise ship was built at a cost of $400 million.

This sentence simply means that the cruise cost $400 million.

Can you explain to me what the sentence imply , especially at a cost and that?

Comment: The cost (price) at which they get their electricity is competitive (similar, thus, *able to compete* in the market) with the cost of other energy sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *cost* here simply means the price. The cost of a loaf of bread is the price of a loaf of bread, for example.

In the Original Poster's extract the word *cost* is being post-modified by an adjective phrase headed by the word *competitive*:

- competitive with that of other energy sources

Because this adjective phrase is long it cannot precede the noun *cost*

- a competitive cost
- a [competitive with the cost of other energy sources] cost <sub>(ungrammatical)</sub>
- a cost [competitive with the cost of other energy sources]

In the example above, the word *cost* appears twice. In the Original Poster's example, the second occurrence of *the cost* has been replaced with the pronoun *that*:

- a cost competitive with that [= *the cost*] of other energy sources.

Some grammarians would regard this adjective phrase as a reduced relative clause where the pronoun and the verb *BE* have been elided through *whiz*-deletion:

- a cost **which is** competitive with that of other energy sources.

Comment: I got it now. so the sentence has nothing to do the phrase "at a cost"?

Comment: @Mrt Well kind of "to get something at a cost" means something like "to get something at a price", but there isn't anything special about the word *cost* here ... Am I making sense?

Comment: Sure, you mean the word cost carries the same meaning in both phrase or only as a noun as in the example.

Comment: @Mrt Yes, that's right. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) He rescued four people at the cost of his own life.= He died saving them.

2) geothermal energy at a cost competitive with that of other energy sources. =

The cost of geothermal energy is about the same as the cost of other energy sources.

3) "that" replaces "the cost" to avoid repetition. Here are more examples:

The population of Canada is smaller than that of the US. ("that" replaces "the population")

Grammar:

(that of : singular noun)

The climate of Mumbai is better than that of  Chennai.

(those of: plural noun)

The students of our school are better than those of their school.

http://www.englishgrammar.org/correct-demonstrative-pronouns/

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the first sentence has such  meaning .Mostly at a cost is used you lose something  to some extent but I think when it concerns life, it win or lost..

Comment: 1) at the cost of his own life. = he died  2) "Energy efficiency may come at the cost of consumer confidence." There is a risk; nothing has been lost yet. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23272/the-difference-between-come-at-a-cost-of-to  3)No going back, whatever happened, even at the cost of his own life. There is a risk. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-the-cost-of